# How to get cookies values after closing and opening browser window using angularjs 1.x?

Tags: angularjs, cookies, cookiestore

I am setting values in angularjs cookies using following code

```
$rootScope.user= "Sai";
$cookieStore.put("userdata",$rootScope.user);
```

and try to get same cookie value after closing and opening browser window using code

```
$cookieStore.get('userdata');
```

but it is coming back `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: This is probably because AngularJS cookieStore does not make stored cookies persistent. Go with localStorage or native JS approach?

Comment: we have to set any expire date? any sample code...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you have provided, your cookies are being set as session cookies. You will need to set additional options when setting a cookie, like `expires` option.

Also, if you can, try to use `$cookies` since `$cookieStore` is deprecated. [You can find additional info here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies).